# Generating a subring inside a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $K:=\mathbb{Z}[u_{j}^{\pm}:j \in J]$, $J$ finite, be a ring of Laurent polynomials and let $A:=K(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ be a field of rational functions in $n$ variables. Now, let $S=\{u^{\alpha}:\alpha_i \geq 0 \}$ be a finite set of (finite) monomials with non-negative powers only. Consider the subring $\mathbb{Z}[S]$ of $A$ generated by $S$. I am not sure what $\mathbb{Z}[S]$ would look like. I think that this is (as a set) literally a polynomial ring in $S$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, that is, there aren't any Laurent polynomials in it. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These have names! They are called *semigroup algebras*. In general, they are not polynomial rings. For example, if $S = \{x^2, xy, y^2 \}$, then
$$\mathbb{Z}[S] \cong \mathbb{Z}[a,b,c]/\langle ac - b^2\rangle.$$
The isomorphism just sends $a \mapsto x^2$, $b \mapsto xy$ and $c \mapsto y^2$. These sorts of rings are interesting in their own right, and they show up as coordinate rings of affine toric varieties.

Just to add a little more. These will form a polynomial ring if and only if $|S| = n$ and when you arrange the exponent vectors appearing in $S$ in a matrix, the matrix has determinant $\pm 1$.

Comment: The latter being equivalent to the exponent vectors forming a basis of $\mathbb Z^n$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module.

Comment: Ohh yeah, I can't just take an arbitrary subset of exponent vectors and expect to be able to generate (over $\mathbb{Z}$) every exponent vector with it. Just so I understand correctly. I take a set $S$ (with or without identity) and build the set consisting of all possible products of elements of $S$ - that (together with multiplication) gives me a semigroup. Then I take formal sums over a ring (or more generally, over a field)  which together with suitably define operations (on that set) will give us the semigroup algebra. Is this correct?